# Regulating precision in dimension reduction

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am having a problem trying to minimize the distortion when compressing/decompressing a set of parameters.

Let me try to explain. I have a space of parameters $q_1$,$q_2$,...,$q_n$.

Since these parameters have some level of correlation, I am using PCA to compress these variables, so that I have a smaller set of uncorrelated variables $r_1$,...,$r_m$, with $m<n$.

When I try to reconstruct the original variables, naturally I will have some error added in the approximation. Let's call the set of original variables $Q$, and the reconstructed set $Q'$

In my problem I have a function $D(Q,Q')$ that measures the distortion between my original set and the reconstructed one. Ideally, I would like to minimize this distortion, but this function is not linear ($Q$ is composed of rotational data), and it is cumbersome to compute it.

However, I can make some assumptions about my parameters. Some of them are more important than the others. For example, I know that when calculating the distortion, any approximation error added to $q_1$ has a bigger effect on the distortion than $q_2$. This means that while I don't want to completely ignore $q_2$, I would $q_1$ to have a higher precision when performing the inverse PCA.

Is there a way for me to regulate the precision, or add specific weight to a dimension when performing dimension reduction?

Comment: What's the exact definition of your distortion metric $D$?

Comment: There are a few details that I omitted from this question, just for clarity.
Let me clarify.

The set $Q$ is composed of a set of Euler Angles. They define the orientation of a human model (like [this](http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/bvh-2-10241.html)  ).

From the orientation of your model, you can obtain the actual position of your joints. This process is known as [Forward Kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_kinematics).

$D$ is the distance between two models, measure joint by joint. This distortion measure is known as Mean Squared Error.

Comment: I decided to omit this part because I feel this problem could be generalized to other scenarios.